# Refreshing browser does not work after changing CSS

Tags: css, firefox, refresh

When I change my css and save it, nothing is changing in my browser (Both firefox and safari)
When i reset safari and empty cache i see the changes on my website.

I have never had this problem before, does anyone has a solution for me?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try ctrl+r to reload everything

Comment: Yes I have done this, but nothing changes. I first have to reset the browsers to see the difference.

Comment: You can manually remove the cache by going to Tools -> Clear Recent History and selecting "Cache" and "Everything from the beginning"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could turn off the cache while you develop. In Firefox, insert `about:config` in the address bar and set:

```
network.http.use-cache = false
```